# vb.net: Minesweeper clicking events

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, handler, minesweeper

I've started making a Minesweeper game in vb.net using a dynamically created grid of buttons, which are stored in a 2D array. I have another 2D array (`Boolean`), that keeps track of whether a certain position is covered or uncovered. And I have an 'update grid' method that can be ran whenever, to update the grid, so that all that should be uncovered is uncovered on the screen.

How would I make it so that when any button is clicked, that button's state is set to uncovered? I tried using an event handler, but I couldn't pass any arguments, and I need to know the button's x and y position, so I can uncover the correct button.

Thanks.

Comment: Find the *sender* back in the array of buttons.  Or use the Tag property.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm having some issues with the 'sender' idea, mainly that I can't use arguments, which is what I need. But the tag property is looking very good. The only problem is that I can only set the tag property to one value, and I need two, one for the X coordinate, one for the Y coordinate. So is there a way to either send two values, send coordinates as one value, or send a value as a string, and later convert that string into a variable name?

Comment: You only need one, it can reference a class object with lots of info.

Comment: You should know how many rows/columns are in the grid, so you can set the tag to an integer value that represents the number of cells from the bottom left corner, then back out the X/Y if you need it. E.G. For a 5x5 grid a tag value of 9 would yield X=4 and Y=2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all your buttons in a `Dictionary(Of Button, Boolean)` each with the value `True`. Later in your Click event handler cast the sender to Button and set the corresponding entry in the dictionary to `False`.

Somewhat like this (excuse my bad VB, I'm normally using C#):

```
 Buttons = new Dictionary(Of Button, Boolean)()
 For Each button in YourButtonArray
     Buttons.Add(button, True)
 End

 ' Click handler:
 Dim clickedButton = CType(sender, Button)
 Buttons(clickedButton) = False
```

**Update:** Alternatively -- as @Hans Passant pointed out in the comments to your question -- you can use the `Tag` property, which would be simpler.

Comment: What does "cast the sender to Button" mean?

Comment: Typecasting. Your event handler knows its `sender`. Cast this to the type Button so you can use it as the key in your dictionary.